# Create Exact Online companies en mass

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

To simulate an accountancy environment, I need to create at least 100 of Exact Online companies (divisions, administraties, dossiers). This can be achieved using a manual action, repeated 100 times. And repeated across 7 countries. In totaal 700 times approximately one minute.

Is there a way to create these numbers of companies automatically through either the REST or XML API?

The documentation on REST API does not list POST possibilities; the XML API does not describe anything about what upload/download features are applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact Online support explained me that there is a way, used by portals of large accountants.

The `Administrations` topic on XML supports to some extent the creation of companies. It does not matter into which company you upload the XML for a new Exact Online company, it gets added as an independent company.

Code sample to create 100 companies, having a human number 501..600:

```
insert into UploadXMLTopics 
( topic
, payload
, division_code
, orig_system_reference
, orig_system_group
)
select 'Administrations'
,      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">
    <Administrations>
        <Administration number="' || 500+id || '">
            <Name>Leeg ' || id || '</Name>
            <AddressLine1>Harm Buiterplein ' || id || '</AddressLine1>
            <Postcode>2501 TH</Postcode>
            <City>Den Haag</City>
            <State code="ZH" />
            <Country code="NL" />
            <Currency code="EUR" />
            <Phone>0351448695</Phone>
            <Fax>0351448690</Fax>
            <Email>info@leeg' || id || '.nl</Email>
            <HomePage>www.leeg.nl</HomePage>
            <ChamberOfCommerce>12411369</ChamberOfCommerce>
            <COCEstablishmentNumber>99</COCEstablishmentNumber>
            <ActivitySector code="A" />
            <ActivitySubSector code="01" />
            <SBICode code="014" />
            <CompanySize code="G" />
            <BusinessType code="51" />
            <StartDate>2015-05-13</StartDate>
            <BlockingStatus>0</BlockingStatus>
        </Administration>
    </Administrations>
</eExact>'
,      sdn.code
,      'Create-admin-' || id
,      'Create-admin'
from   exactonlinexml..calendar clr
join   ( select min(code) code from exactonlinerest..systemdivisions ) sdn
where  clr.id between 1 and 100
```